# Swift/BLE Notifications not working

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, notify

I am using the Ti sensortag to play around with bluetooth and sensors. My goal is to get the barometer and the buttons working. The buttons notify when pressed but the barometer never notifies or changes its value at all. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate{

    var centralManager:CBCentralManager!
    var blueToothReady = false
    var connectingPeripheral: CBPeripheral!

    let data = "01".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextView!

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startUpCentralManager()
    }

    func startUpCentralManager() {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func discoverDevices() {
        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: (NSDictionary), RSSI: NSNumber!) {

        println("Discovered: \(peripheral.name)")
        textField.text = textField.text + "Discovered: \(peripheral.name)\n"


        self.connectingPeripheral = peripheral
        centralManager.stopScan()
        self.centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)

    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) { //BLE status
        var msg = ""
        switch (central.state) {
        case .PoweredOff:
            msg = "CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off"
            println("\(msg)")

        case .PoweredOn:
            msg = "CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready"
            blueToothReady = true;

        case .Resetting:
            var msg = "CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting"

        case .Unauthorized:
            var msg = "CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized"

        case .Unknown:
            var msg = "CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown"

        case .Unsupported:
            var msg = "CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform"

        }
        textField.text = textField.text + "\(msg)\n"

        println(msg)

        if blueToothReady {
            discoverDevices()
        }
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!,didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!)
    {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices([CBUUID.UUIDWithString("F000AA40-0451-4000-B000-000000000000"),CBUUID.UUIDWithString("FFE0")])
        println("Connected")
        textField.text = textField.text + "Connected\n"

    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!)
    {
        if let servicePeripherals = peripheral.services as? [CBService]
        {
            for servicePeripheral in servicePeripherals
            {
                println("Service: \(servicePeripheral.UUID)")
                textField.text = textField.text + "Service: \(servicePeripheral.UUID)\n"
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: servicePeripheral)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func refreshBLE(sender: UIButton) {
        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {
        if let charactericsArr = service.characteristics  as? [CBCharacteristic]
        {
            for charactericsx in charactericsArr
            {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: charactericsx)
                println("Characteristic: \(charactericsx)")
                textField.text = textField.text + "Characteristic: \(charactericsx)\n"

                peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(charactericsx)
            }

        }
    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {
        if var data :NSData = characteristic.value {
            textField.text = textField.text + "Data: \(characteristic.value)\n Notifying: \(characteristic.isNotifying)\n"
            println("Data: \(characteristic.value)\n Notifying: \(characteristic.isNotifying)")
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the attribute table: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/a/a8/BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf

Why do I only get the initial value of the barometer and no notifications?

Comment: According to that document you need to write 0x01 to 0xAA42 to start the barometer and 0x01 to 0x2902 to enable notifications

Comment: thx, I tought so too, but on the other hand I haven't done this for the buttons so I was confused. I tried                 peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: <#CBCharacteristic!#>, type: <#CBCharacteristicWriteType#>) but did not manage to define the right data object. Can you help me once again more plz

Comment: Did you download the sample code from ti?  I just took a look and it shows the various characteristics that you need to write to

Comment: I got the SENSORTAG-IOS-OSX source code example written in objective-c and I found the relevant code. Problem is I don't know anything about objective-c. Do you have a swift example code maybe?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you look in deviceSelector.m you can see the UUIDs you need. `d` is just a dictionary. If you are going to write iOS code then I think you will need to learn something about Objective-c as there is so much code and examples in that language. It isn't that much different from any other language except for the [] notation for method invocation so someObj.somefunc() in swift would be [someobj somefunc]